Mostrar +1 (1 visto) correctamente con localStorage al reproducir video
Estoy diseñando un sistema de contador de visualizaciones de vídeo.
Tengo una lista de arreglos desde donde muestro la información en toda la tarjeta mediante una función incorporado en el arreglo.
const datos = [
{
tipo: {
  id: 1,
  categoria: "Categoría"
},
perfil: {
  nombre: "Nombre perfil de tarjeta 1"
},
media: {
  titulo: "Big Buck Bunny",
  url: "video.mp4",
  visto: () => {
    let este = localStorage.getItem("1");
    return este;
  }
 }
}
];

La id: 1 es el nombre que toma localStorage.getItem("1").
En la tarjeta muestro así:
${item['media'].visto('este')}

Cuando abro un item y reproduzco el vídeo, dentro de esa función también se guarda en localStorage +1 según el id del vídeo que proviene de la tarjeta y a su vez de la lista de arreglos.
//setInterval(()=>{

  let yoId = yoVideo.getAttribute("data-id");
  
  let esto = Number(localStorage.getItem(yoId)) +1;
  
  localStorage.setItem(yoId, esto);

//},1000);

Para escribir el "más uno", quise ponerle un atraso de por lo menos 2 segundos o más, después de reproducir el vídeo (para ver el cambio reflejado), pero esto no me funciona.

No sé ve reflejado al instante sino, al recargar la página.
Al escribir con un retraso mediante setInterval, no agrega +1
sino: de dos en dos.

Desearía poder mejorar esta parte para mejor funcionamiento pero, después de muchos intentos vine aquí.
Mi proyecto es muy extenso, pero creé esta simple redundancia para el ejemplo necesario aquí (solo que aquí no funciona el localStorage).


const datos = [
{
            tipo: {
                            id: 1,
                            categoria: "Categoría"
            },
            perfil: {
                            nombre: "Nombre perfil de tarjeta 1"
            },
            media: {
                            titulo: "Big Buck Bunny",
                            url: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4",
                            visto: () => {
  let este = localStorage.getItem("1");
  return este;
}
            }
},{
            tipo: {
                            id: 2,
                            categoria: "Categoría"
            },
            perfil: {
                            nombre: "Nombre perfil de tarjeta 2"
            },
            media: {
                            titulo: "Elephants Dream",
                            url: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4",
                            visto: () => {
  let este = localStorage.getItem("2");
  return este;
}
            }
},{
            tipo: {
                            id: 3,
                            categoria: "Categoría"
            },
            perfil: {
                            nombre: "Nombre perfil de tarjeta 3"
            },
            media: {
                            titulo: "Nombre del vídeo",
                            url: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4",
                            visto: () => {
  let este = localStorage.getItem("3");
  return este;
}
            }
}
];

let todos = '';

datos.forEach( (item) => {
            
            todos += `
              <div class="tarjeta">
                <div class="perfil">${item['perfil'].nombre}</div>
                <a href="${item['media'].url}" data-id="${item['tipo'].id}" class="titulo accion">${item['media'].titulo}</a>
                <b>${item['media'].visto('este')} vistas</b>
              </div>
            `;
            
});

const escribir = document.getElementById("all");
escribir.innerHTML = todos;

const accion = document.querySelectorAll("a");
const yoVideo = document.getElementById("yoVideo");

function accionModal(e) {
            
            const este = e.target;
            const info = e.target.parentNode;
            const url = este.getAttribute("href");
            const id = este.getAttribute("data-id");
            
            const tit = document.querySelector("#titulo");
            const vis = document.querySelector("#vistas");
            const vistas = info.querySelector("b");
            
            yoVideo.setAttribute("data-id", id);
            tit.innerHTML = este.textContent;
            vis.innerHTML = vistas.textContent;
            reproduccion(url, yoVideo);
            
};

function reproduccion(url, video) {
            
            video.src = url;
            video.load();
            setTimeout( () => video.play(),300);
            
            //setInterval(()=>{
                            let yoId = yoVideo.getAttribute("data-id");
              let esto = Number(localStorage.getItem(yoId)) +1;
                            localStorage.setItem(yoId, esto);
            //},1000);
            
            
};

accion.forEach( (ev) => {
            ev.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                            accionModal(e);
                            
                            e.preventDefault();
                            
            });
}); 
*,html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.visor {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease
} .visor video {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: calc(100% - 35px);
    transition: all 0.3s ease
}

.botonera {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
    background-color: rgba(0 0 0 / 0.5)
} .botonera #titulo {
    font-size: 22px
}

#all {
    display: flex;
    columns: 3 300px;
    gap: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    
    @media(width < 576px) {
            columns: 1;
            column-gap: .50rem;
            padding: .50rem;
            flex-direction: column
    }
}

.tarjeta {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgba(42 59 71 / 0.7)
}
.tarjeta .perfil {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 .50rem;
    background-color: rgba(42 59 71 / 0.7)
}
.tarjeta .titulo {
    display: block;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .30rem 1rem;
    border-radius: .20rem;
    color: blue;
    background-color: lavender
}
<div class="visor">
<video controls="" data-id="" id="yoVideo">
<source src="">
  </video>
  <div class="botonera">
<div id="titulo">Titulo</div>
<div id="vistas">vistas</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div id="all"></div>




Una función callback podrá ayudar en la ejecución del conteo de visualizaciones después de algún evento.
La función callback se inicializará cuando el video sea reproducido o con un retraso de 2 segundos.
let todos = '';

datos.forEach((item) => {
  todos += `
    <div class="tarjeta">
      <div class="perfil">${item['perfil'].nombre}</div>
      <a href="${item['media'].url}" data-id="${item['tipo'].id}" class="titulo accion">${item['media'].titulo}</a>
      <b>${item['media'].visto()} vistas</b>
    </div>
  `;
});

const escribir = document.getElementById("all");
escribir.innerHTML = todos;

const accion = document.querySelectorAll("a");
const yoVideo = document.getElementById("yoVideo");

let viewedVideos = {}; //  almacenar vídeos ya contabilizados


function aumentarVistas(id, vistasElement, callback) {//callback de llamada aumentará las vistas
  
  setTimeout(() => { // 2 segundos de retraso
    let vistasAtual = Number(localStorage.getItem(id)) || 0;
    vistasAtual += 1;
    localStorage.setItem(id, vistasAtual);

   
    vistasElement.innerHTML = `${vistasAtual} vistas`; // actualiza el contador.
    document.querySelector(`#vistas`).innerHTML = `${vistasAtual} vistas`; 

   
    if (callback) callback();// La callback de llamada puede inicializarse si se produce un recuento más tarde.
  }, 2000);
}

function accionModal(e) {
  const este = e.target;
  const info = e.target.parentNode;
  const url = este.getAttribute("href");
  const id = este.getAttribute("data-id");
  
  const tit = document.querySelector("#titulo");
  const vis = document.querySelector("#vistas");
  const vistas = info.querySelector("b");
  
  yoVideo.setAttribute("data-id", id);
  tit.innerHTML = este.textContent;
  vis.innerHTML = vistas.textContent;
  reproduccion(url, yoVideo, vistas, id);
}

function reproduccion(url, video, vistasElement, id) {
  video.src = url;
  video.load();
  setTimeout(() => video.play(), 300);
  

  if (!viewedVideos[id]) {  // Esta condición es para evitar más de un cargo.
    video.addEventListener("play", () => {
      aumentarVistas(id, vistasElement, () => { // Callback  se puede inicializar si se produce un conteo y luego realizará acciones después del conteo
        console.log(id);
        
        viewedVideos[id] = true;// vídeo ya visto
      });
    });
  }
}

accion.forEach((ev) => {
  ev.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    accionModal(e);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});


Exelente. Mucho código y más de lo que pence pero funciona bien. Gracias

Copié el código del "ejemplo necesario" que pusiste en tu pregunta, trate de ejecutarlo y noté 2 cosas:

Cuando haces click sobre el  y ejecuta accionModal() que al final ejecuta reproduccion() el código funciona bien, es decir, si puedo ver en el local storage como se aumentan de uno en uno la cantidad de reproducciones, y según el video al que doy click los valores en el localStorage se aumentan correctamente.
No veo en el la función reproduccion() la parte del código que "reimprime" esos valores en el html una vez que se han actualizado en el localStorage, por esto es que necesitas actualizar la página para ver los cambios
Nunca me pasó que se aumentara de 2 en 2, siempre aumentó de 1 en 1, ese problema no se puede replicar con este código

Por otro lado para poder ejecutar el código de ejemplo tuve que hacer algunos ajustes mínimos al código de javascript, pero al final pude ejecutarlo sin problema.
Entonces, acá está el código de ejemplo con las ediciones que le he hecho:
visor.html
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="vistas.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">

<div class="visor">
<video controls="" data-id="" id="yoVideo">
<source src="">
  </video>
  <div class="botonera">
<div id="titulo">Titulo</div>
<div id="vistas">vistas</div>
  </div>
  </div>
<div id="all"></div>

vistas.js
...
const datos = [
{
    tipo: {
                id: 1,
                categoria: "Categoría"
            },
    perfil: {
                nombre: "Nombre perfil de tarjeta 1"
            },
    media: {
                titulo: "Big Buck Bunny",
                url: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4",
                visto: () => {
                    let este = localStorage.getItem("1");
                    return este;
                }
            }
},
{
    tipo: {
                id: 2,
                categoria: "Categoría"
            },
    perfil: {
                nombre: "Nombre perfil de tarjeta 2"
            },
    media: {
                titulo: "Elephants Dream",
                url: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4",
                visto: () => {
                let este = localStorage.getItem("2");
                return este;
                }
            }
},
{
    tipo: {
                id: 3,
                categoria: "Categoría"
            },
    perfil: {
                nombre: "Nombre perfil de tarjeta 3"
            },
    media: {
                titulo: "Nombre del vídeo",
                url: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4",
                visto: () => {
                    let este = localStorage.getItem("3");
                    return este;
                }
            }
}
];

let todos = '';

datos.forEach( (item) => {
            
            todos += `
              <div class="tarjeta">
                <div class="perfil">${item['perfil'].nombre}</div>
                <a href="${item['media'].url}" data-id="${item['tipo'].id}" class="titulo accion">${item['media'].titulo}</a>
                <b>${item['media'].visto('este')} vistas</b>
              </div>
            `;
            
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    const escribir = document.getElementById("all");
    escribir.innerHTML = todos;
    
    
    const accion = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    const yoVideo = document.getElementById("yoVideo");
    
    Array.from(accion).forEach( (ev) => {
        ev.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
                        accionModal(e);
                        e.preventDefault();
                        
        });
    }); 
});

function accionModal(e) {
            
            const este = e.target;
            const info = e.target.parentNode;
            const url = este.getAttribute("href");
            const id = este.getAttribute("data-id");
            
            const tit = document.querySelector("#titulo");
            const vis = document.querySelector("#vistas");
            const vistas = info.querySelector("b");
            
            yoVideo.setAttribute("data-id", id);
            tit.innerHTML = este.textContent;
            vis.innerHTML = vistas.textContent;
            reproduccion(url, yoVideo, este);
            
};

function reproduccion(url, video, este) {
            
            video.src = url;
            video.load();
            setTimeout( () => video.play(),300);

            let yoId = yoVideo.getAttribute("data-id");
            let esto = Number(localStorage.getItem(yoId)) +1;
            localStorage.setItem(yoId, esto);
            /* acá se actualiza el html */
            yoVideo.closest('div').querySelector('div[id="vistas"]').innerText = esto + ' vistas'; //el reproductor
            este.closest('div').querySelector('b').innerText = esto + ' vistas'; // las vistas en "este" (que es la tarjeta actual)
            
            
};

Separé como vez el código en un archivo llamado vistas.js, y es prácticamente el código que tenías con unas pequeñas modificaciones:

modifiqué la función accionModal() para que a reproduccion tambien le pase "este"
modifiqué la función reproduccion() para que reciba "este", y al final de la función, despues de que ya actualizaste el valor en el localStorage se "reimprimen" o "actualizan" los textos de la cantidad de vistas tanto en el reproductor como en "este" (que es la tarjeta actual)


Con estos ajustes yo tengo el ejemplo funcionando y se comporta como esperabas, espero que te sirva, saludos.

